# Convert simple JSON to SQL SELECT Statement

Tags: sql, json, azure, t-sql

I have the following JSON:

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @json = N'[
  {"@odata.context":"http://www.example.com","value":[
  {"financialmovements_ID":1,"Data":"2020-02-10T00:00:00Z","ES":"E","Descri\u00e7\u00e3o":"FIV-005 3\u00baTRM19/20","Valor":455.9700,"ActGlbActDescr":"Reg. Financ. Pag.","ActGlbContr":"FIV005","ActGlbContrDescr":"Cond FIV-005"},
  {"financialmovements_ID":2,"Data":"2019-11-14T00:00:00Z","ES":"E","Descri\u00e7\u00e3o":"Pag. Cond FIV005","Valor":1958.6600,"ActGlbActDescr":"Reg. Financ. Pag.","ActGlbContr":"FIV005","ActGlbContrDescr":"Cond FIV-005"}]}
]'
```

I'm trying to convert to SQL as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.value')
WITH (
    --financialmovements_ID INT '$.financialmovements_ID',
    Data DATETIME2 '$.Data',
    [E/S] NVARCHAR(max) '$.ES',
    DescTrs NVARCHAR(max) '$."Descri\u00e7\u00e3o"',
    Valor MONEY '$.Valor',
    ActGlbActDescr NVARCHAR(max) '$.ActGlbActDescr',
    ActGlbContr NVARCHAR(max) '$.ActGlbContr',
    ActGlbContrDescr NVARCHAR(max) '$.ActGlbContrDescr'
);
```

All i get is an empty resultset (0 rows when it should be 2 rows), what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON has square brackets round the whole thing, meaning it is an array (it only has one element) so your OPENJSON starting point will have to be `$[0].value`

Comment: No probs. Don't forget to click the grey tick under the vote numbers to turn it green if it's the answer to your problem, and upvote an answer (plus any others) if you found them useful